# How to show the DIV related with clicked link and hide other DIVs with Jquery?

Tags: jquery, toggle, show-hide, slidetoggle

As I summarized at topic I want to show the DIV related with clicked link and hide other DIVs with Jquery. To be able to understand what I am saying, please visit [Worldlines](http://ahmetkemal.com/worldlines/)

You will see there the topics related with some news. When somebody clicked on a topic the news div will slide-down below clicked topic and previously read news div will hide.

I think I told what I want clearly.

Thank you,

Comment: Have you written any code?  This is not a site to have people write the code for you.  Try and do it and post the problems you have then we can help.  If you want the code written hire a programmer or go to a different site.  Also, look here for some hints: http://jqueryui.com/demos/accordion/

Comment: Hi Hogan,

I am sorry if I reflect myself as a "freeloader", no I am not! I am not a senior programmer but yes, I have coded some websites. The answer that I hope to get was just the hint you gave. :)

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Jquery Accordion was what I look for. You can find it here http://jqueryui.com/demos/accordion/

Answer (score 0):

You'll add a script at the beginning of your html like so:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/jquery-1.4.1.min.js"></script> 
<script type="text/javascript">

    function showPanel2() {
    $('#Panel1').hide();
    $('#Panel2').show();
    }

</script>
```

This will hide one panel and show another. The "Panel1" and "Panel2" are simply the IDs of the panels you'll be showing or hiding.  And then you'll have the following code on your button:

```
 <input type="button" onclick="showPanel2();" value="Submit" />
```

This should be simple enough to modify if you want to hide multiple panels.

Comment: Thanks Mark. Your comment is suitable for only 2 divs and if I use many divs, also should add many lines for every div.

What I was looking for is Jquery Accordion. http://jqueryui.com/demos/accordion/